# Pandas Opening up .dat File as an Array of Arrays

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following .dat file

https://github.com/lukepolson/School/blob/master/Phys%20411/Assignment%205/JamesBay_temperature.dat

When I open it in pandas using

```
df_james = pd.read_csv('JamesBay_temperature.dat', sep=" ",
                        skiprows=[0,1,2], names=['Temperature'])
```

the values it contains are an array of arrays:

```
In [18]: df_james.values
Out[18]:
array([[ 4.89],
       [ 4.89],
       [ 4.89],
       ...,
       [14.77],
       [14.67],
       [14.67]])
```

Why is pandas doing this? Is it something about the file I'm opening, or am I using pd.read_csv wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The result that you obtained is not an array of arrays. It is a single numpy array object with `float` entries:

```
In [1]: arr = df_james.values

In [2]: type(arr)  # Show object type
Out[2]: numpy.ndarray

In [3]: arr.dtype  # Show data type of array entries
Out[3]: dtype('float64')   

In [4]: arr.shape  # Show number of rows and columns
Out[4]: (2979360, 1)
```

Comment: I respectfully beg to differ. When I type df_james.values[0] I get the output array([4.89]). This is an issue, because I want to plot the values.

Comment: The expression `df_james.values[0]` creates a new array object. To directly extract the first float value you have to use `df_james.values[0, 0]`.